# Ray only using two threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ray

I wrote this

```py
@ray.remote
def check(word, words):
    valid_ciphertexts = []
    for key in range(26):
        ciphertext = shift(word, key)
        if ciphertext in words:
            valid_ciphertexts.append(ciphertext)
        else:
            valid_ciphertexts.append(None)
    return valid_ciphertexts


if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = set()
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as lexicon:
        for word in lexicon:
            words.add(word.strip())
    ray.init()
    results = ray.get([check.remote(word, words) for word in words])
    with open(sys.argv[2], 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([key for key in range(26)])
        writer.writerows(results)
```

I was expecting to see high usage across all my cores, due to parallelising the hundreds of thousands of calls to `check`, but the dashboard is showing this:

[image]

Why is it like this?

Comment: Note that this is answered here. https://discuss.ray.io/t/ray-only-using-two-threads/2085

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on https://discuss.ray.io/t/ray-only-using-two-threads/2085

> Can you try
>
> ```
> ray.init()
> words_ref = ray.put(words)
> results = ray.get([check.remote(word, words_ref) for word in words])
> ```
>
> I’m wondering if this is because words it’s taking too long to keep re-serializing words

That worked for me:

[image]

> I’m confused as to why there’s a difference here to be honest, I thought Python was pass-by-reference anyway?

> ... The issue is that Ray doesn’t have a way of knowing if words has changed between calls, so it keeps re-putting it in the object store.